# Android: How safe is PBKDF2 with a 4 digit pin?

Tags: encryption, android, account-security, pbkdf2

Our Product Manager wants a **4 digit** pin for login in our app, obviously for UX reasons, so user don't have to remember their password each time when they login.

A refresh token can be retrieved from backend to obtain a session token, which have access to the API. On our app, we encrypt the refresh token with **AES and PBKDF2**. A random salt and IV are generated plus the 4 digit used as password for PBKDF2.

After the encryption, I store the salt, IV and the cipher text base64 encoded in private shared preference.

The encryption code looks like this:

```
const val CPR_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
const val ALGORITHM_TYPE = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"
const val ITERATION_AMOUNT = 12000
const val KEY_SIZE = 256

private fun encrypt(passCode: String, data: ByteArray): Encrypted { //e.g.: passCode = "0000"
    val salt = ByteArray(256)
    SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt)

    val iv = ByteArray(16)
    SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CPR_TRANSFORMATION)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(passCode, salt), IvParameterSpec(iv))
    val raw = cipher.doFinal(data)
    return Encrypted(salt.encodeBase64(), iv.encodeBase64(), raw.encodeBase64())
}

private fun getSecretKey(passCode: String, salt: ByteArray): Key {
    val pbKeySpec = PBEKeySpec(passCode.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATION_AMOUNT, KEY_SIZE)
    val keyBytes = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM_TYPE).generateSecret(pbKeySpec).encoded
    return SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES)
}
```

#### Now my question is: How secure is this implementation?

- How could an attacker retrieve the refresh token from shared
  preference and decrypt it?
- Is the symmetric key inside secure element?
- How safe is this implementation against malware or root?
- How easy can the key be brute forced? (except that user tries 10k
  times manually to insert the correct pin)

Comment: Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem. Could you make your question more specific?

Comment: hey, I am not asking you to break the security, or asking for concrete steps how to do that. Just want to know the general vulnerabilities of my implementation, since we have no security experts in the company and are wondering how "easy" it would be.